# form component duplication in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to create a simple form with form field/component duplication feature.

I searched all over the web. But i couldn't find any proper tutorial.

For example my form fields contains the following.

```
1. Title
2. Email

3a. Image Name 
3b. Image Description
3c. Image file
```

3a,3b,3c are a group here. So lets call it as "image group".
I would like to have a duplicate link below that group where my users click it and duplicate as many as they want.

[Here is an example](http://www.jformer.com/demos/team/) of what i'm asking. 
Ps: I dont want to use jformer. Because it loads all the script and it taking to much time to load the page. Thats why i'm asking this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is write a JavaScript function that will append a new set of form elements to a given container. Something like this:

```
<div id="imageforms">
    <fieldset id="firstimage">
       <input type="text" name="imagenames[]" />
       <textarea name="imagedescriptions[]"></textarea>
       <input type="file" name="imagefiles[]" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="addAdditionalImage(); return false;">add another image</a>
```

And then you need the JavaScript function:

```
 function addAdditionalImage() {
      $('#imageforms').append($('#firstimage').clone());
 }
```

The most interesting part here is the usage of `name="xxx[]"` which tells PHP to create an array from the form values.

Comment: Hello till, thanks for your answer. But its the php code i'm worried about. Can you give me some sample php code?

Comment: Just use `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_FILES);` to look at how PHP creates these arrays from the form values.

Answer (score 1):

since you tagged your question as being jquery related you should take a look at the clone method here: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

you need to group the fields that can be duplicated (let's say enclose them in a span) so that you would have a selector for all of them, clone and then use methods like append or prepend to "inject" the same elements again

you should use arrays for names if you want to process those values on the server side (input type="text" name="image_name[]")